# wpf windowstyle none border style

Tags: wpf, resize, windowless

I have wpf application 
I'm using WindowStyle none and I'm adding window controls by my self ( minimize, close )

but WindowStyle none still has window resize border

window resize border is fine but I want to style it to look same in windows xp , vista , 7

I saw solution setting noresize but i need window to be normally resizeable ( without resize grip )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set `WindowsStyle` to none, and you want to remove resize border you must build a custom resize window.

Read [this](http://digitalmoosetracks.com/blog/wpf-transparent-window-with-resizing) article. It will help you.
The idea is that you a bunch of handles around the window and handle the resize events with the SendMessage() API call in `user32.dll`.

There are nice code examples. Hope that I helped you.

Comment: isn't it possible to change window system border color using windows API ?

Comment: When I nedded this I used a timer with `Interval = 100` miliseconds. It was modifying the window size. I used a very simple code that was showing my mouse position on the screen and the window position. When I was pressing on the windows corner the window was resizing using bool values and that timer. Sure this is not so efficient but it works. I haven't used Windows API yet... I don't know how to use it. You know, you can get the window position on the screen using this.Left and this.Top. :)

Comment: @Console I have a project where I used it, so I will note to update this answer soon. Thanks for ping.